# How to Split an XML file into multiple XML Files

Tags: c#, xml, split

I am trying to split a XML file to multiple small xml files in C#.net and am
trying to get the best possible approach to this. Any help on this will be
great... Sample example on what I am trying to do...

### Source XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATABASE>
  <DOC>
    <DOCID>8510188</DOCID>
    <ISSUE>2010</ISSUE>
    <CAT>Literature and Art</CAT>
    <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
    <TEXT>Test</TEXT>
  </DOC>
  <DOC>
    <DOCID>1510179</DOCID>
    <ISSUE>2012</ISSUE>
    <CAT>Miscellaneous</CAT>
    <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
    <TEXT>Test</TEXT>
  </DOC>
</DATABASE>
```

### Should split to two xml documents as below

1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATABASE>
  <DOC>
   <DOCID>8510188</DOCID>
   <ISSUE>2010</ISSUE>
   <CAT>Literature and Art</CAT>
   <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
   <TEXT>Test</TEXT>
  </DOC>
</DATABASE>
```

2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DATABASE>
  <DOC>
    <DOCID>1510179</DOCID>
    <ISSUE>2012</ISSUE>
    <CAT>Miscellaneous</CAT>
    <TITLE>Test</TITLE>
    <TEXT>Test</TEXT>
  </DOC>
</DATABASE>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I'd use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
var newDocs = doc.Descendants("DOC")
                 .Select(d => new XDocument(new XElement("DATABASE", d)));
foreach (var newDoc in newDocs)
{
    newDoc.Save(/* work out filename here */);
}
```

(I'm assuming you want to save them. Maybe you don't need to. I've tested this just by printing them out to the console instead.)

Comment: Thank you   
But it gives this error  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added System.Linq to your usings-list at the top of your file?

Comment: @AML: Include namespace `System.Linq` and `System.XML.Linq` in usings section.

Comment: Error again
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'Save' and no extension method 'Save' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XDocument>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @AML: Sorry, that should be `newDoc.Save`.